# How to improve performance/speed of DOM jquery DataTable with 9,999 rows?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, datatables

for 'SEO'/client reasons, I have to run with a DOM jquery datatable (http://datatables.net/index) rather than a server side table. I've tried to explain that this is going to cause a performance drain but wanted to see if there are any steps I can take to improve the rendering of a datatable with 9,999 rows? I require the sorting on all columns as well. At the moment, it's taking around 6 seconds and hangs the page/tab from rendering.

Any suggestions (apart from going serverside/ajax)?

Thanks,
David

Comment: Just to clarify, you're initializing a jQuery DataTable on an existing html table with 9,999 rows?

Comment: I'd suggest using slickgrid for this, it handles large numbers of rows without impacting performance, and has sorting/filtering.

Comment: @BLSully Yeah. Exisiting dom table. It must be dom data, not ajax/js data in this case.

Comment: I think the problem the OP is running into is a combination of 1) Forget JS, DOM rendering of 9,9999 rows is just going to suck regardless. 2) DataTables (or any table plugin) then having to parse the data out of the unwieldy enormous DOM is also going to take a while.

Frankly, the approach needs to change. I use DataTables daily and I know it can be quite fast with 10k+ rows, as long as you're giving it a straight JSON source.

Could you set a JS variable = to the data you need in a 2D array and then set your `aaData` == the assigned variable?

Comment: 10K rows is going to be slow without hooking up a grid. lol

Comment: What are the _SEO reasons_? Will Google index megabytes worth of html?

Comment: @jrummell the total size of the page is actually 500kb (still pretty heavy though). But it's the DataTables sorting and styling that hangs the page. The table initially displays quite quickly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps an approach would be to create a dummy DOM rendering of the table for the "SEO" reasons (moved outside the viewport) and then another visible table generated with JSON with which the user actually interacts. JSON should be a lot faster.

Comment: This is a possible 'solution'.